# Why is my code subtracting 1 instead of adding 1?

Tags: python, while-loop, tkinter, label, global-variables

I have a program which is meant to pick words from a list and display them on a label and remove them.

Every time the user enters the word correctly their `word_count` will go up by 1 and if they get it wrong it goes down by 1.

```
import random
import tkinter

words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Alpha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Advanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discombobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]
word_count = 1

def nextWord():
        global word_count

        entry.focus_set()

        while word_count <= 12:
                random_word = random.choice(words)
                label.config(text=str(random_word))
                entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
                word_counter.config(text="Words: " + str(word_count))

                if entry.get().lower() == random_word.lower():
                        entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
                        word_count += 1
                        word_counter.config(text="Words: " + str(word_count))
                        wrong_label.config(text="")
                        words.remove(random_word)

                elif entry.get().lower() != random_word.lower():
                        entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
                        wrong_label.config(text="WRONG!")
                        word_count -= 1
                        word_counter.config(text="Words: " + str(word_count))
                break

def startGame(event):
        nextWord()        

window = tkinter.Tk()          
window.title("Fastest Typer")

label = tkinter.Label(window, font=("Helvetica", 60))
word_counter = tkinter.Label(window, text="Words: " + str(word_count), font =("Helvetica", 14))

wrong_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="", font =("Helvetica, 14"))
entry = tkinter.Entry(window)

window.bind("<Return>", startGame)

label.pack()
word_counter.pack()
wrong_label.pack()
entry.pack()

entry.focus_set()

window.mainloop()
```

**My question is:** When the above program is run and you type the word correctly, the `wordcounter` displays -1 instead of 1 and -2 instead of 2, etc. Also, the text of `wrong_label` won't change when they get it right aswell.

**UPDATE**

I've tried to reorder my code as the following but now the `word_count` won't increase or decrease at all:

```
import random
import tkinter

words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Alpha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Advanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discombobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]
word_count = 1

def nextWord(event):
        global word_count

        entry.focus_set()

        while word_count <= 12:
                random_word = random.choice(words)
                entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
                label.config(text=str(random_word))
                words.remove(random_word)
                return

        if entry.get().lower() == random_word.lower():
                entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
                word_count += 1
                word_counter.config(text="Words: " + str(word_count))
                wrong_label.config(text="")

        elif entry.get().lower() != random_word.lower():
                entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
                wrong_label.config(text="WRONG!")
                word_count -= 1
                word_counter.config(text="Words: " + str(word_count))     
                entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)

def startGame(event):
        nextWord()

window = tkinter.Tk()          
window.title("Fastest Typer")
frame = tkinter.Frame(window)

label = tkinter.Label(frame, font=("Helvetica", 60))
word_counter = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Words: 0", font =("Helvetica", 14))
wrong_label = tkinter.Label(frame, text="", font =("Helvetica, 14"))
entry = tkinter.Entry(frame)
window.bind("<Return>", startGame)

label.pack()
word_counter.pack()
wrong_label.pack()
entry.pack()
frame.pack()

entry.focus_set()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: By `while word_count <= 12 ..... break` do you mean `if word_count <= 12`?

Comment: It's meant to be a loop so it runs 12 times.

Comment: Try printing how many characters entry.get().lower() consists of, and likewise for random_word.lower(). The code's gone into the elif branch, so check character by character and see which letter is considered to be different.

Comment: Tried `print(len(entry.get().lower()))` and `print(len(random_word.lower()))` and it prints nothing. Probably something to do with the `if` statement.

Comment: Do print(...) before the if-elif-break structure.

Comment: `random_word` matches the length of the words in the list but `entry.get()`  produces 0

Comment: That's why the code keeps diverting to the elif branch.

Comment: Yes but `word_count` is still less than 12 so I don't understand why the if-statement isn't working

Comment: An unconditional `break` will mean it doesn't loop.

Comment: If I try using `return` or without anything, the program will crash

Comment: It is the latter but if I did that the code wouldn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

You are **never** getting a correct word becuase of a logic error in you code. Whenever you press the Enter key, `startGame` is called, which then calls `nextWord`. The `nextWord` function then **produces a new random word**, compares it to what you've currently typed, and **displays the new word** on the screen.

Comment: So do I need to just reorder it or completely rewrite it?

Comment: @Inkblot I think that the at least the`nextWord` function needs to be rewritten.